# Solr issue with escaping special characters

Tags: solr, schema, special-characters

I am having issues with special characters in the search term sent to the solr through query.
When I search for a part number 123-45, I should get 2 results i.e., 123-45 and 12345.
Please let me know how I can do this and also the configuration I need to use in schema.xml
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that's the only character you want to remove, use a PatternReplaceFilterFactory to replace the "-" with "" when you're indexing and querying:

```
<analyzer>
  <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="-" replacement="" />
</analyzer>
```

The KeywordTokenizer will keep the whole term as a separate token, and the PatternReplaceFilterFactory will remove any `-` and replace it with nothing, meaning that both the indexed and the queried term will be normalized to `12345`.

Answer (score 0):

Use fuzzy search `123-45~0.1`

it searches for string token, which has Levenshtein distance close to 0.1.